# Itunes connect "Invalid Binary iPad Application"

Tags: ipad, udid, uidevice

I'm submitting an update of an existing  iPad  application on behalf of one of my clients, after about 10 minutes, the status changes to "Invalid Binary" with absolutely no explanation why?

Today I have receive one mail from apple

> "Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6."

But I have not used uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice.

I have use third party mobclix version 6.1.2 api and revMob ads.Accodring to mobclix support **"new advertising Identifier (AID), which will replace UDID for iOS 6 "**

Comment: any other third party lib in your project? if not, you could ask mobclix for help

Comment: i am alerdy conatct with mobclix team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your RevMob sdk Version You use revmob sdk 5.6.1 in which they  are not collected UDID  anymore. you download new sdk from this link

http://sdk.revmob.com/ios_download.html

And also you sure you are use latestest MobClix SDK you also download latest SDK from this link

https://developer.mobclix.com/help/general/download